# Manipulate event URL <a> tags

Tags: fullcalendar

I am passing a URL to my fullCalendar implementation via a JSON string.

fullCalendar wraps all the event data inside the  tags of this URL.

I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate this  as to add a call to a javascript function.

Something like:

```
<a href="myLink.aspx" onClick="myFunction()"> my Link</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the "eventRender" to add a .click() event or .bind(click)...

Something like this might work...

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    $("a").click(function(){
        myFunction();
    });
}
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for...